# Pass Windows credential as PSCredential in Powershell script using C#

Tags: c#, wcf, powershell, iis

I have a WCF service which executes remote powershell scripts and returns the results to client. But when this WCF is hosted on IIS i get following error at invoke line.

```
using (var powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                var command = new PSCommand();
                command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
                command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
                command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", connectTo);
                command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Kerberos");

                powershell.Commands = command;
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;

                var result = powershell.Invoke();//Error
                psSessionConnection = result[0];
            }
```

*Processing data from remote server #EXCHANGESERVERNAME# failed with the following error message: [AuthZRequestId=ac0dedbe-a345-4eac-bb8d-cd5b8eab327c][FailureCategory=AuthZ-CmdletAccessDeniedException] The user #MACHINENAME# isn't assigned to any management roles.*

How can i make this line

> command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Kerberos");

pass the user credentials?

Comment: What account is running the application pool that is hosting the service?  Based on the error message my first guess would be the account doesn't have the proper permissions (but I'm not familiar with PowerShell).

Comment: If you are not using local domain authentication `Kerberos` might not work, you can use `Basic` instead, also you need to add a credential object like: `command.AddParameter("Credential", yourcredentialobject);`

Comment: @Tim The WCF is running under default pool with ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Comment: @Avshalom Adding command.AddParameter("Credential", yourcredentialobject); works but that not the intent. I dont want to hard code the credentials. Only specific AD group has to access this WCF and is it possible to pass their credentials in command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Kerberos");